# Using multiple ivy:retrieve patterns in my build.xml to associate with multiple artifact patterns

Tags: java, xml, ant, ivy

I have files in two different directories that I would like to publish.  One set of files has a .jar extension the other set doesn't have any extension at all.

In my build.xml file under publish I have the following code:

```
<ivy:publish resolver="public-publisher" conf="default"
   deliverivypattern="${build}/${delivery.pattern}">
  <artifacts pattern="${build}/[artifact].[ext]"/>
  <artifacts pattern="${misc}/bin/[artifact]"/>
</ivy:publish>
```

then when I do my retrieve I tried to do something like:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="ivyLib/[artifact].[ext]" conf="default" />
<ivy:retrieve pattern="ivyLib/[artifact]" conf="default"/>
```

but that didn't work.  It puts a . after my files that don't have any extensions on them.  Now I'm all out of ideas and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="ivyLib/[artifact](.[ext])" conf="default" />
```

the () makes the contents of the () optional so it should match `ivyLib/Foo` and `ivyLib/Foo.jar`

Comment: mmm I tried using the (.[ext]) but it still gives me the . at the end of my files.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think you need it in the resolver definition as well, what does that look like now?